# A coordinate Geometry problem

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]

Given above the geometry figure, how can I find out the coordinates of Q, as a function of 'A'? The outer square is circumscribed on the outer circle, while it itself inscribes the inner circle. The inner quadrilateral is a rectangle.

Comment: $|OQ|$ is $r \sqrt{2}$ and the coordinate offsets from $O$ to $Q$ will be given by $r \cos \theta$ and $r \sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle $OQ$ makes with the positive $x$ axis, that can be obtained from $A$. BTW, it would be nicer to embed the image.

Comment: What have you tried? Here (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good guide on how to ask questions. Include your steps. Include your sources. Include the part you are stuck on. It's this easy to make a good post.

Comment: A good way to find this is to use polar coordinates, where as @PaulAljabar said the coordinate change can be expressed as $(+r \cos \theta, +r \sin \theta)$. You also need one last piece of information - what is the direction of r (the argument in polar coordinates)?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I tried and found out PQ, to be r*sin(A)/sin(<PQO). Now, <PQO is tan-1( altitude/base * sin(A) ), which comes out to be tan-1(sin(A) / (sqrt(2) - cos(A)).

Comment: I'm sorry about the poor presentation, as I'm new to the math forum here. Besides, I'm trying to solve it to get a programming task done.

Comment: I don't think you need to calculate the length of $PQ$ to find the coordinates of $Q$. The length of $OQ$ and the angle it makes with the $x$ axis should be enough.